# Equations of above three variables cannot be solved with dimensional analysis. What does that mean?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

I came across this statement while Googling about dimensional analysis. At first I thought that I understood what the statement meant, but now I realize that I really have no idea. What does the statement mean exactly?

Comment: Google and study the Buckingham Pi Theorem.

Comment: Odd. I'm sure I recall a numerical methods problem of about 5 variables solved by dimensional analysis (which is too much like magic for my taste) - or at least a solution pathway laid out. I'll have to find my notes.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com)?